# Leaflet maps. map disappears when changing coordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've embedded a custom svg map of the office with leafletjs. For some reason works with example coordinates:

As soon as I change this coordinates the map stops displaying on the browser, it disappears.

I'm using html file on the browser. Vanilla JavaScript and leafletjs library, you can try with any svg map you find on the internet. you'll get the same error.

here's the code: https://gist.github.com/Mschemmari/621d04639ff25c3be4d006f315dfa953

Expected result: to have my map displayed with its real latitud and longitude. Actual results: Map is not showing with actual lat Long coordinates.

Comment: Did you get the commenting out wrong? You've left the live map `center` with the example data `imageBounds` - which don't match.

Comment: yes, i just edited it. thanks

Comment: You should post the code you actually run, rather than an edited version. That would save everyone's time.

Comment: the entire code is now on a git gist. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: So the problem is still what I said originally - you've got 2 sets of coordinates - example and real - the uncommented `center` is from one and the uncommented `imageBounds` is from the other. Your commenting went wrong.

Comment: if you try example coordinates and example center works. if you try the real one doesnt.